# Usando um objeto em diferentes métodos no Objective C

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, ios, objective-c

Estou tentando trabalhar com objetos no iOS Objective C, e tive uma dúvida com relação a utilização.

Eu criei um arquivo chamado `carro.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface carro : NSObject
{
    NSString *_marca;
    NSString *_ano;  
}
@property (strong) NSString *marca;
@property (strong) NSString *ano;
@end
```

no arquivo `carro.m` eu tenho o seguinte

```
#import "carro.h"
@implementation busca
@synthesize marca;
@synthesize ano;
@end
```

Eu tenho uma `ViewController` e quero usar esse objeto atribuindo valor ou resgatando o valor. Porém como fazer com que o mesmo objeto possa ser utilizando em diferentes métodos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiramente, por convenção, nomes de classe em Objective C tem a primeira letra maiúscula.
Na maioria dos casos, não é necessário sintetizar a propriedade. O compilador gerará automaticamente a variável de instância. Ex: ao declarar `@property (strong) NSString *marca;` o compilador vai gerar automaticamente a variável de instância `_marca`. A variável de instancia só é acessível na implementação da classe. Já o acesso à propriedade depende dos modificadores na declaração: readonly, readwrite(default).
Segue um exemplo:

Carro.h

```
@interface Carro : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *marca;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *modelo;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger ano;
@end
```

Carro.m

```
@implementation Carro
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _marca = @"VW";
        _modelo = @"Fusca";
        _ano = 1979;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
//Exemplo de utilização da classe Carro
@implementation ViewController {
    Carro *carro;
}

- (void)methodA {
    carro = [Carro new];
    NSLog(@"%@ %d", carro.modelo, carro.ano);//Fusca 1979
    [self methodB];
}

- (void)methodB {
    [carro setAno:2014];
    [carro setModelo:@"Gol"];
    NSLog(@"%@ %d", carro.modelo, carro.ano);//Gol 2014
}
```

Se está em dúvida quanto a conceitos de orientação a objetos e MVC sugiro estudas esses tópicos antes de aprofundar os estudos em Objective C.