# Como passar dados(string) de uma classe para a TextField da Viewcontroller

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, objective-c, classes, xcode

Quero passar dados de uma classe do tipo `NSObject` para serem mostrados na minha `TextField Viewcontroller`. Tentei utilizar a função `prepareForSegue` mas não consegui.

Alguém sabe como se passa os dados, mesmo que seja utilizando a função `prepareForSegue` ou outra forma de passar os dados.

Comment: É possível detalhar mais ou incluir algum código? A pergunta está um pouco obscura.

Comment: Obrigado por responder mas eu já achei algo parecido com aquilo que quero [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17472/usando-um-objeto-em-diferentes-metodos-no-objective-c] .      O que eu quero tem ha ver com os MVC, e quando fiz a pergunta eu não soube explicar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não pode settar o texto para o UITextField (ou qualquer outro componente como o UILabel ou UITextView) no metódo `prepareForSegue`, pois todas os componentes da view controller destino ainda não estão allocados(nesse momento todos eles são nil). Eles só estarão allocados quando o viewController for apresentado.

O certo é criar uma property NSString na viewController destino e então settar o texto da textField com a property criada.

Dessa forma:

No `prepareForSegue` use o seguinte:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"ViewController2"])
    {
        ViewController2 *vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc2.myString = self.textField.text;
    }
}
```

e dentro do viewController destino no método `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    (...)
    self.textField.text = self.myString;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, sim essa é uma das soluções. Felizmente eu já terminei o projeto há algumas semanas e o método que utilizei para passar os dados foi o Singleton.